# File Management with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, file-transfer, file-management

So, I've run into an interesting issue.

I am writing a PowerShell script to Check folder "A" for identical file names as found in folder "B". If they are found in folder "A", they are moved to folder "C". However, if there are multiple files within folder "A" I need them to be renamed when they are moved to folder "C".

```
$folderA = 'S:\Folder A\' # Folder to remove cross-folder duplicates from
$folderB = 'S:\Folder B\' # Folder to keep the last remaining copies in
Get-ChildItem $folderB | ForEach-Object {
    $pathInA = $folderA + $_.Name
    If (Test-Path $pathInA) {Move-Item $pathInA -Destination 'S:\Folder C\'}
}
```

Which does a great job at finding and moving, but not so much renaming. Any recommendations for me?

EDIT: I'm sorry, I should have specified. The most useful way of renaming would either be xy.txt > xy_1.txt   .... or .... xy.txt > xy(1).txt

And the purpose for re-naming them is we have a file structure where we create a pdf with a digital signature for a hand receipt for a machine coming in to be worked on (Folder A). It then gets signed by a tech when the work is completed, and when that happens it gets saved into another folder (Folder B). And eventually gets picked back up by the customer which is an entirely different location (Folder D). Which is another signature and saved into that folder. Once it reaches Folder D, all other copies are useless as they don't have all signatures on them, and they are just remnants. I really hope that makes sense, and if it does not, please let me know.

Comment: how do you want to rename the file? any logic?

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have specified. The most useful way would either be xy.txt > xy_1.txt   .... or .... xy.txt > xy(1).txt

Answer (score 1):

You haven't mentioned how you want to rename your Files or for what purpose.
still, this will do the trick. right now it will just add a number to the Filename. so `xy.txt` will be `xy1.txt` in the new folder etc.

```
$i = 1
$FolderB = gci "S:\Folder B" | select -expand Name
$FolderA = gci "S:\Folder A" | ? { $_.Name -in $FolderB } | % {  
    Move-Item $_.FullName "S:\Folder C" -PassThru | 
    Rename-Item -NewName ($_.BaseName + $i + $_.Extension)
    $i++
}
```